# How is a shear pad of remote compliance device formed?

Tags: design

I am researching on mechanical design of [remote compliance devices (RCC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Center_Compliance)<sup>†</sup>. In the RCC, manufactured by ATI, they use shear pads for lateral compliance. They mention that shear pads are elastomers bonded with metal shims. I couldn't find how it is being made. Are there layers of elastomers between wedging pieces (shims) or something else? How is adhesion being achieved?

[image]

<sup>† From wikipedia: "In robotics, a Remote Center Compliance, Remote Center of Compliance or RCC is a mechanical device that facilitates automated assembly by preventing peg-like objects from jamming when they are inserted into a hole with tight clearance."</sup>